# Androidアプリで画像切り替えの遅さを改善するには

Tags: android, java

お世話になっております。ノベルゲームを作っているものです。
タイトル通り画像表示について困っています。

私はキャラをベースの体、腕、目、口に分けていて、それらを重ねて表示し、ボタンを押したときに画像を変える処理を書きました。しかし、実機で試したところボキャラを表示する動作がUXにかかわるくらい遅いのです。
なぜ、普通のノベルゲームのようにサクサク動かないのでしょうか？これを改善するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
下に記すコードはキャラを表示するactivityのメソッドです。

```
public void message(View view) {
   //メッセージのビューに名前テキストを入れるメソッド
    mes();
    //名前のビューに名前テキストを入れるメソッド
    name();
    //キャラのビューにキャラを入れるメソッド
    chara();

    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
    num++;
    number = String.valueOf(num);
}

private void mes(){
    Resources res = getResources();
    Button message = findViewById(R.id.message);//メッセージボタンのidを取得。
    int strId = getResources().getIdentifier("message" + number, "string", getPackageName());//numberを使い動的にIdを取得。
    message.setText(res.getString(strId));
}

private void name() {
    Resources res = getResources();
    TextView name=findViewById(R.id.name);//名前テキストビューのIDを取得。
    int nameId = getResources().getIdentifier("name" + number, "string", getPackageName());//numberを使い動的にIdを取得。
    name.setText(res.getString(nameId));
}
private void chara() {
    ImageView base = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.base);
    int baseId = getResources().getIdentifier("base" + number, "string", getPackageName());
    base.setImageResource(baseId);/

    ImageView ude = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ude);得。
    int udeId = getResources().getIdentifier("ude" + number, "string", getPackageName());
    ude.setImageResource(udeId);

    ImageView me = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.me);
    int meId = getResources().getIdentifier("me" + number, "string", getPackageName());
    me.setImageResource(meId);

    ImageView kuchi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kuchi);
    int kuchiId = getResources().getIdentifier("kuchi" + number, "string", getPackageName());。
    kuchi.setImageResource(kuchiId);

}
```

一応、自分で考えた解決策で、解像度を下げること、キャラを一枚にまとめること、この二つを出しました。
前者は、試したところ画像の質が許容できないくらい下がってしまい、却下となりました。
後者はまだ試していません。やはり細やかな表情を出すために、部分分けはしたいです。それに部分分けしたほうがアプリが重くならないと思うのです。（実際に、ほかのノベルゲーム製作エンジンでは部分分けをしていました。）

この他にどんな対策が考えられるでしょうか？
はっきりいって今、私は深い森の中で道を見失ってしまっているような状態です。
この森を抜けだす、方角だけでも、指針だけでも教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 解像度を下げると画質が許容できないというのは解りましたが、
解像度を下げた結果、動作速度としてはどうだったのでしょうか?
また、部分分けについても、最終的に部分分けはするとしても、
原因の切り分けのために、一枚にまとめてどうなるのかは確認してみると良いのでは?
原因が判れば、その原因を回避しながら満足の行く質を得る方法も見つかるかもしれませんよね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！そうですね.....確かに原因が解像度ではない場合もあるかもしれませんしね.....問題が発生したらその原因を追及する、この心構えを忘れていたかもしれません。もう一度根本から見直してみます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

androidのことは詳しくないですが参考までに思ったことを記述します。
getResources()が呼ばれすぎだと思います。
データリソース(画像類)は別に動的に追加するつもりはないですよね？
動的に組み合わせたいだけでデータ自体は静的なものだと思います。
それならばActivityのフィールドに

```
Resources res;
```

を宣言してOnCreate()にてres=getResources()を一度だけ代入すればよさそうに思えます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！よく考えれば、回答者さまのおっしゃる通りでした！プログラミングに関して、駆け出し中の駆け出しなので、こんな間違いをと思うと、自分が恥ずかしいです...本当にありがとうございました！